# ViewWillLayoutSubviews giving wrong frame after presentViewController

Tags: ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller, interface-orientation

I've been using `pushViewController:animated`: but noticed it was deprecated, so switched over to `presentViewController`:.

Doing an `NSLog` inside of the `viewWillLayoutSubviews`: method, I get a width of `768`, when the iPad is landscape and therefore its actual width is `1024`. Turning it a few times shows the same width of 768 every time. This does not happen when I use `pushViewController`.

Any ideas why this isn't working as expected, and how I could fix it?

Comment: pushViewController:animated: is not depreciated.

Comment: You're right, it's not. I was getting it confused with something else. Still, the problem remains. I can switch back to pushViewController, but still with presentViewController, I can't get it to accept the correct frame.

Comment: Use the bounds instead, that should give you the correct values.